# How is the definition of "torture", the noun, related to "punishment"?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, word-usage

How is the definition of "torture", the noun, related to "punishment", and why are they used together for the title of this article?:

[Medieval Torture and Punishment](http://www.medieval-life-and-times.info/medieval-torture-and-punishment/)

... And I just noticed that the page extended further than I thought, with these:

> Definition of Torture
>
> The definition of torture is the deliberate, systematic, cruel and wanton infliction of physical or mental suffering by one or more torturers in an attempt to force another person to yield information, to make a confession, as part of a punishment or for any other reason. Torture devices or tools are used to inflict unbearable agony on a victim. The objectives of torture were to intimidate, deter, revenge or punish. Or as a tool or a method for the extraction of information or confessions.

And,

> Definition of Punishment
>
> The definition of punishment is to impose or inflict something unpleasant or aversive on a person in response to disobedient or morally wrong behavior. Punishment means to impose a penalty for a wrong committed.

Comment: torture = the application of (extreme) pain; it can be as part of a punishment. Punishment = the "application" of a penalty; does not necessarily involve pain. Otherwise, which dictionaries have you tried?

Comment: The word "torture" can be used very figuratively. For example: _Getting through that lecture was pure torture._ I won't say more on the matter, though, until you comply with the request by @pazzo - you really should consult a dictionary first, and then tell us what you found and where you found it. [More here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Answer (score 1):

*Punishment* means something unpleasant that must be done or feels like it is being done in response to a wrongdoing.  Punishment is more about the reason for going through something unpleasant/painful than the degree.

*Torture* is where one deliberately inflicts (often extreme) unpleasantness or pain on another purely for his/her/its own pleasure or to force another to do something.  Torture is more about the degree of unpleasantness/pain than the reason why.

You might be tortured outside of a punishment scenario - for example, you are robbed and tortured to give up your ATM password.  It's not in response to a wrongdoing but is still torture.

And obviously not all punishment is torture.

Comment: There are more figurative uses of the word _torture_, too, where the word is used somewhat facetiously to mean "emotionally taxing". Some examples: _Waiting for Christmas morning was torture. Driving through rush hour traffic is torture. Mycompany tortured me by not calling me for more than two weeks after my interview._ Nothing "deliberate" going on in those examples – just regular human impatience.

Comment: This only answers the first half of the question: How is the definition of "torture", the noun, related to "punishment? Still needs: why are they used together for the title of this article? Which is "Because medieval methods of punishment often involved methods similar to torture, such as the rack."